# Reportlab graphics and bullets

Tags: python, reportlab

I am trying to figure out a good way to do this.  I see that there is a way to do bulleted lists in reportlab, the only problem is that this assumes that the bullets will be some sort of text character (like a "*" or "-").  What I am trying to figure out is what is the best way to use an image as the bullet in a flowable frame?  Any insight on how best to go about this would be appreciatded.

Thanks,

RB

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I know of the way bullets are done, you'd probably be best off developing a custom flowable that replicates bullet list functionality but lets you choose the bullet to be an image.  Admittedly, not a great solution, but it would get the job done.  The way bullets are implemented depends somewhat heavily on text layout and isn't really equipped to replace the bullet character with an image.

At least that's as far as I understand ReportLab internals.

Comment: I am looking into that as a possible solution.  Before doing that I wanted to see if someone else had tried a possibly better solution.